# Truffle test: Problem with understanding the test

Tags: truffle-test, mocha

I am trying to understand the test provided at:

[Tutorial](https://ftsrg.mit.bme.hu/blockchain-ethereumlab/guide.html)

```
("Test balance after deposit", function() {
        return SimpleBank.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            sb = instance;
            return sb.deposit({ from: accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ether') });
        })
```

The smart contract code is given below:

```
contract SimpleBank{
   uint public transactions;
   mapping (address=>uint) balances;
   
   function deposit() public payable{
      balances [msg.sender] +=msg.value;
      transactions++;
   }
}
```

The test invokes :

```
sb.deposit({ from: account[0], value:  web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ether') });
```

To which account the ‘10’ ether is going from account[0]? What is the purpose of 'transactions' state variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 Ethers goes to the contract `SimpleBank` and stays there. In the `deposit` function the contract sets some additional data which marks who sent how much Ethers, but this is only contract's internal book-keeping and doest't move any Ethers anywhere.

As for the `transactions` variable, it probably just shows how to use a state variable. It doesn't have any real benefit, it's just an example. As is all of the contract - just an example for reference purposes.

Comment: how can we check the balance of SimpleBank?